# C String parsing errors with strtok(),strcasecmp()

Tags: c, string, strtok

So I'm new to C and the whole string manipulation thing, but I can't seem to get strtok() to work. It seems everywhere everyone has the same template for strtok being:

```
char* tok = strtok(source,delim);
do
{
 {code}
 tok=strtok(NULL,delim);
}while(tok!=NULL);
```

So I *try* to do this with the delimiter being the space key, and it seems that strtok() no only reads NULL after the first run (the first entry into the while/do-while) no matter how big the string, but it also seems to wreck the source, turning the source string into the same thing as tok.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
char* str;
scanf("%ms",&str);
char* copy = malloc(sizeof(str));
strcpy(copy,str);
char* tok = strtok(copy," ");
if(strcasecmp(tok,"insert"))
{
 printf(str);
 printf(copy);
 printf(tok);
}
```

Then, here is some output for the input "insert a b c d e f g"

```
aaabbbcccdddeeefffggg
```

"Insert" seems to disappear completely, which I think is the fault of strcasecmp(). Also, I would like to note that I realize strcasecmp() seems to all-lower-case my source string, and I do not mind. Anyhoo, input "insert insert insert" yields absolutely nothing in output. It's as if those functions just eat up the word "insert" no matter how many times it is present. I may* end up just using some of the C functions that read the string char by char but I would like to avoid this if possible. Thanks a million guys, i appreciate the help.

Comment: You can copy `str` with `char* copy = strdup(str);` instead of using `malloc` incorrectly, and forgetting to actually perform the copy.

Comment: You shouldn't call `printf` with an unknown string as the first argument.  The first argument is a format string that uses `%` delimited format specifiers to interpret subsequent arguments.  If any of your unknown strings contain a `%`, bad things will happen.  Use `puts(str)` , `fputs(str, stdout)`, or `printf("%s", str)` instead.

Comment: `strtok` mutates the string it is scanning by replacing the delimiters with `NUL` terminators.  If you print `copy`, after running `strtok` on it, you will only ever see the first token, since the `NUL` terminator is never removed after being inserted.  However, each call to `strtok` with a `NULL` first argument will pick up where the previous call left off (just after the delimiter that is now a `NUL`), and scan forward from there, returning the token that started at that position.

Comment: `strcmp` and `strcasecmp` return the lexicographic difference between the two strings.  When the strings are equal, it returns `0`, which is a false value in C.  If you want the body of the `if` to execute when `tok` is equal to `"insert"`, then you should explicitly check the return value for `0`.  i.e. `if(strcasecmp(tok, "insert") == 0)`.

Comment: The `%s` `scanf` format specifier reads a whitespace delimited string, so you're only going to get `"insert"` in your buffer.  The rest of the input is still going to be sitting in the stdin buffer.

Comment: `strcasecmp` does not modify the source string; the prototype shows that the arguments are of type `const char *`, which indicates that the function does not intend to modify them.  The function merely compares each character in a case-insensitive manner.

Comment: Your template which you claim "everyone seems to have" is wrong, you should check `tok` for NULL before using it. Changing do...while to an ordinary `while` loop would fix this.

Answer (score 1):

With the second snippet of code you have ***five*** problems: The first is that your format for the `scanf` function is non-standard, what's the `'m'` supposed to do? (See e.g. [here for a good reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) of the standard function.)

The second problem is that you use the address-of operator *on a pointer*, which means that you pass a pointer to a pointer to a `char` (e.g. `char**`) to the `scanf` function. As you know, the `scanf` function want its arguments as pointers, but since strings (either in pointer to character form, or array form) already are pointer you don't have to use the address-of operator for string arguments.

The third problem, once you fix the previous problem, is that the pointer `str` is *uninitialized*. You have to remember that uninitialized local variables are truly uninitialized, and their values are indeterminate. In reality, it means that their values will be seemingly random. So `str` will point to some "random" memory.

The fourth problem is with the `malloc` call, where you use the `sizeof` operator on a pointer. This will return the size *of the pointer* and not what it points to.

The fifth problem, is that when you do `strtok` on the pointer `copy` the contents of the memory pointed to by `copy` is uninitialized. You allocate memory for it (typically 4 or 8 bytes depending on you're on a 32 or 64 bit platform, see the fourth problem) but you never initialize it.

So, five problems in only four lines of code. That's pretty good! ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for the speedy and thorough rely. I forget what the "m" stands for but it essentially allows me to allocate the memory for str dynamically. I'm not sure why, but for the whole scanf("%ms"... line that is the only way I can seem to read in a string without getting a segmentation error. That portion was actually given to me by the teacher. I can try to work around that, but I'm not sure what you meant by the third problem. Doesn't scanf initialize str to the value that comes through stdin? After all, str does seem to hold at least part of the value it is given after...

Comment: @user3118524 The first, second and third problem are related. If that `'m'` code allocates memory for the string, you can probably disregard those points. The two other points are still valid though.

Comment: strcasecmp and strtok. I think part of my problem in understanding is that I assumed "initialized" is synonymous with "defined" which it appears it is not (don't worry, I'm off to research now :) ). As for the fourth problem, that was the only way I could seem to allocate enough space in a new string for the strcpy command (which is missing from my posted snippet). This is actually not a copy-paste because I am using some sort of app to connect to my uni's linux platform. Thank you so much for the help thus far. I'll do my best to correct based on what you said and post results.

Comment: wow youre fast :D ... As for the fourth problem, if I dont call strtok, then copy seems to work perfectly fine as str would for printf and such. They even come back as identical with strcmp.

Comment: @user3118524 For the fourth points, you do know about the [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) function? Actually, you can solve both the fourth and fifth problem (in my answer) by using the (actually non-standard but exists everywhere) `strdup` function.

Comment: @user3118524 Well I have nothing better to do right now than drink more wine and hang around on SO... :)

Comment: Sorry friend, I had to goto work and got caught up spring-breaking =D I'm back on the case though, and will try to sort this out again later tonight. Thanks again for the help!

EDIT: I've got work tonight, so I'll have to check it tomorrow. Sorry to keep you waiting

Comment: I know tomorrow came awfully late =P but yes we actually went over this in class, that strdup was the way to go with this problem, so you were spot on. Thanks a bunch my friend. I need 15 rep to upvote, but I assure you, that unlike when I said "tomorrow" a month or two ago, I shan't forget the help, and will upvote you as soon as I get the opportunity =D

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to print space delimited tokens following the word "insert" 3 times.  Does this do what you want?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char str[BUFSIZ] = {0};
    char *copy;
    char *tok;
    int i;

    // safely read a string and chop off any trailing newline
    if(fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin)) {
        int n = strlen(str);
        if(n && str[n-1] == '\n')
            str[n-1] = '\0';
    }

    // copy the string so we can trash it with strtok
    copy = strdup(str);

    // look for the first space-delimited token
    tok = strtok(copy, " ");

    // check that we found a token and that it is equal to "insert"
    if(tok && strcasecmp(tok, "insert") == 0) {
        // iterate over all remaining space-delimited tokens
        while((tok = strtok(NULL, " "))) {
            // print the token 3 times
            for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                fputs(tok, stdout);
            }
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }

    free(copy);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not at my home PC but I am certainly going to try this upon returning home. Thank you so much for the reply, and sorry for the wait =)